# How to add new event + mini calendar next to day view+full calendar plugin

Tags: asp.net, fullcalendar

How to add new event + mini calendar next to day view+full calendar plugin

Answer (score 0):

this tutorial pretty much nails it:
http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/02/02/linking-jqueryui-datepicker-and-fullcalendar.aspx